# How to configure LinuxMint 17 to invoke commands from the mouse?

Tags: linux-mint, mouse, window-manager, mate-desktop, audio-volume

My PC runs LinuxMint 17 in the 64-bit MATE edition. How can I configure X (or MATE?) to invoke these two commands from my mouse (which is a 6-button Logitech M705)?

- send the clicked window behind all others by holding [ALT] and clicking [mouse button 4]
- minimize the clicked window to the task bar by holding [ALT] and clicking [mouse button 5]
- adjust the master audio volume by holding [ALT] and rolling the scroll wheel

That is, just like you can normally hold [ALT] and click [mouse button 1] to *move* a window, I would like to hold [ALT] and click [mouse button 5] to *minimize* the window.

Mouse button 4 and 5 basically correspond to the "Forward" and "Back" buttons.

**Background:**
I have read (see below) that I can configure `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and/or use a small tool to do it for me, but I currently don't even *have* an `xorg.conf` file, and I am unsure which of the many tools to use -- and most of all, how to specify those actions.

Since I started using BSD/Linux a long time ago, AltDrag became a fixture on my Windows computers at work. Some time ago, I configured some extra stuff in AltDrag which I now long to reproduce on Linux (I'm sure we can all agree that Windows should not be a better experience than Linux ;-).

**Meta:**
I asked this question earlier, but it got "unpublished"(?) because it wasn't clear. I reworded it, but then couldn't figure out how to get it re-published. Some days later I discovered that it was *closed*. This, then, is my re-worded, and hopefully more lucid, version posted as a new question. Apologies for double posting. If this still isn't clear enough, please engage in dialog with me before simply closing my question.

Resources:

- stefansundin.github.io/altdrag/
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManyButtonsMouseHowto
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/All_Mouse_Buttons_Working

Comment: ...hello? *tap tap tap* Is this thing on? ;-) More than a month, and not even a comment? Is there something more I can do to improve the explanation and/or increase exposure (given I don't yet have enough rep for a bounty)?